# How can I only show every third image in the post list?

Tags: html, wordpress, css-selectors

I currently have a list of posts on my home page consisting of the latest posts on my site. Right now every post shows the image but I am looking to only show the 1st, 4th, 8th image etc.. I have tried to use the child tag but all the images seem to be using (1). Any fixes for this?

you can see it [here](https://www.dronenr.com.au/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to apply `nth-of-type` to the post itself (i.e the `article` tag), plus add a selector for the image, so that would be something like

```
article:nth-of-type(2n) .attachment-post-thumbnail,
article:nth-of-type(3n) .attachment-post-thumbnail,
article:nth-of-type(4n) .attachment-post-thumbnail {
  display: none;
}
```

which hides the image in every 2nd, 3rd, and 4th article

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your home page HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="post">
  <img class="post-thumbnail" alt=""/>
</div>
<div class="post">
  <img class="post-thumbnail" alt=""/>
</div>
<div class="post">
  <img class="post-thumbnail" alt=""/>
</div>
<div class="post">
  <img class="post-thumbnail" alt=""/>
</div>
<div class="post">
  <img class="post-thumbnail" alt=""/>
</div>
<div class="post">
  <img class="post-thumbnail" alt=""/>
</div>
<div class="post">
  <img class="post-thumbnail" alt=""/>
</div>
<div class="post">
  <img class="post-thumbnail" alt=""/>
</div>
<div class="post">
  <img class="post-thumbnail" alt=""/>
</div>
<div class="post">
  <img class="post-thumbnail" alt=""/>
</div>
<div class="post">
  <img class="post-thumbnail" alt=""/>
</div>
<div class="post">
  <img class="post-thumbnail" alt=""/>
</div>
```

You have several options to hide some of them:

1. PHP => won't echo an image if the loop index reaches a multiple of 4 (`$index % 4 === 1`). Best solution IMHO, the image you don't need won't be loaded in the DOM and won't be requested.
2. CSS => will hide the img tag `:nth-of-type`. However, I don't think it's the best option, as you render the  tag, load them, then you hide them.

   .post img {
         display: none;
       }
       .post:nth-of-type(4n) {
         diplay: block;
       }